# How to add an image that is local to the pdf generator file, cordova-plugin-pdf?

Tags: cordova-plugins

Good morning I find myself trying to upload an image to the pdf that is generated with this library, but I don't know where in my project I should have the image and how the code should be to import it. Can someone please support me

Structure of my project:

[image]

documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-pdf-generator